# Spark Core Shield PCB design review

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad, layout

I'm designing a PCB (a shield for Spark Core - microcontroller + wifi board). It is connected to 5 analog sensors (not on board, using 3pin header) and 4 relays (on board).

Output(RJ45) and vias on right is for debug and extension purpose.

(images deleted for copyright purposes)

- Bottom Layer: Blue, Yellow
- Top Layer: Red, White
- Pad, Via: Green
- Software used: Eagle

Please tell me anything you think. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Please show your schematic and details of your components. Otherwise, we can't really provide too much insight.

Comment: Does it pass all the DRC's on Eagle?  There's a blue trace going through the 3X6 matrix of pads on the bottom left hand side, that looks very close to the green pads.

Comment: Check if all grounds are contiguous. Next thing, the shift register probably has a capacitor on VCC but its other end is too far from VSS. Also you have shorts at multiple places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got lots of little proximity issues and shorts that Eagle's DRC should have pointed out to you. Did you run the DRC? When you do, it's best to use the design rules provided by the board house you plan to use. For example, [here's OSH Park's design rules](https://oshpark.com/guidelines) (scroll half way down the page). They even provide a .dru file to use directly as your DRC.

I've circled in orange the problems that I could see. As whatsisname suggested, it'd be more helpful if you provided the schematic as well.

[image]
[image]